# Get LVM LV / VG / PV name from UUID

Tags: lvm

The output of `{lv,vg,pv}display` gives:

- Name
- UUID

How do I find an LVM name given a UUID?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can filter LVM commands’ output directly using the `-S` option:

```
# pvs --noheadings -o name -S uuid=MtLb3p-MUle-8fyk-fy6m-z99n-V9mi-xxxxxx
  /dev/sdb3
```

This also works with `vgs` and `lvs` to find VGs and LVs.

To avoid having to deal with the spaces at the start of the output, add `--config 'log{prefix=""}'`:

```
# pvs --noheadings -o name -S uuid=MtLb3p-MUle-8fyk-fy6m-z99n-V9mi-xxxxxx --config 'log{prefix=""}'
/dev/sdb3
```

Answer (score 1):

For PVs **only**, we have the generic case of a block device:

```
$ source=UUID=MtLb3p-MUle-8fyk-fy6m-z99n-V9mi-xxxxxx
$ blkid -t "$source" -o device
/dev/sdb3
```

This will work on any block device (and also with `LABEL=`).

---

Interestingly, you can search `/etc/fstab` with:

```
source=$(findmnt -sno SOURCE --raw "$mount")
```

And `$source` will be of the correct format to pass to `blkid -t`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `{lv,vg,pv}s` command and `awk`, eg:

```
$ uuid="MtLb3p-MUle-8fyk-fy6m-z99n-V9mi-xxxxxx" 
$ sudo pvs -o UUID,NAME --noheadings | awk "\$1 == \"$uuid\" { print \$2 }"
/dev/sdb3
```

Comment: Now you’ve got me wondering — what’s wrong with `-S`?

Comment: And if you really want to go with AWK, `sudo pvs -o UUID,NAME --noheadings | awk "\$1 == \"$uuid\" { print \$2 }"` is slightly shorter (but perhaps less convenient to type).

Comment: I'm going with your version. It seems `-v` is a `gawk`-ism.